# 405 error on api , when called from browsers but status 200 ok on postman why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api

i am new in this topic so kindly go easy.

i have made an api in asp.net mvc model which uses Entity framework to fetch and give response.

i have tested it on postman and all the basic functions are working just fine but when i use the code generated by postman to call api on browser console it gives me 405 error

"OPTIONS http://localhost:56659/api/values 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

"Failed to load http://localhost:56659/api/values: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:56720' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405."

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:56659/api/values",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
alert(“HIT”);
});
```

i have seen multiple solutions but no one could provide a working answer. kindly help

Comment: you need to add a CORS attribute on the web api. If you have already done that and it 's still not working, then share the code.

Comment: thank you so much for helping

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

after following these procedure now the application is working. thanks a lot, and also noticed something else this error occur only in chrome and is working just fine on firefox

Comment: That's great. Also this is not an error. It is a security feature of chrome that is yet to be implemented by firefox. IE considers all localhost websites as same origin irrespective of the port number.